# Ionic call function from Safari/Chrome console(Debug)

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I am developing some ionic app and i have a function for eg.

```
debugfunction(message: string){
   console.log(message);
}
```

now i run ionic cordova run ios, and the applications starts in the simulator, i open safari>development>simulator and i do have access to the console.

Now my question is how can i call the debugfunction so i can debug the code from there?

so that debugfunction('hello world debug') would show up? Not sure if it helps but the function is inside a provider

Comment: Can write debugfunction function in a service (ex. LogService) and call debugfunction wherever you want (ex. LogService.debugfunction('Hello world debug')).

Comment: in my case the function is inside of a provider called NotificationsProvider, and i have a function called testDebugFunction(). In the safari console i try to write, NotificationsProvider.testDebugFunction and i get the following error. 'ReferenceError: Can't find variable: NotificationsProvider
cordova.js:1731'